# Why does a localmacro work in Class Dec, but not if I put it in a Macro object?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I created a macro object in the AOT called "MyMacro".  In it I put:

```
#localmacro.myStrFmt
    'Here is some text before (' + %1 + ') and some after'
#endmacro
```

In my class it works if I have it defined locally in the run method or class dec, but not if I use the #MyMacro.  Is there a different syntax or something?

```
void run()
{
//    #MyMacro
    str retVal;

    #localmacro.myStrFmt
        'Here is some text before (' + %1 + ') and some after'
    #endmacro

    ;

    retVal = #myStrFmt("Text in parenthesis");

    info (retVal);

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead referencing the macro like:

```
#MyMacro
```

You need to reference it like this:

```
#macrolib.MyMacro
```

Comment: THANKS!  This has been driving me nuts.